# Git submodules without detached head?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Maybe I'm using git-submodules not on purpose, but if there's any other git feature which satisfies my case, would be nice to find it.

After cloning repository, I want submodule to be in master branch, I'll never store any additional files inside of chef-starter submodule.

```
git clone git@github.com:holms/vagrant-starter.git
git submodule update --init
cd chef-starter
git branch
   * (detached from 0b6a803)
   master
```

I do understand that it's a nice feature to track that submodule dir tree separately, but it's not my case. After main repository clone, I just want that submodule would be cloned to the latest master stage without any additional fuss.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `git clone --recursive URL dir; cd dir ; git submodule foreach 'git checkout origin/master || :'`

Comment: ok, and when you do git status on repo dir, you'll see "pending commits" in stash after you perform that last checkout command. that's what I don't want to have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The submodule has a detached head because a submodule means "check out a specific commit from the submodule's repository". The `master` branch may have moved forward (it may point to a commit that descends from commit `0b6a803`), so Git checks out the specific revision instead of checking out a branch.

`git-submodule` has the option to record a branch name. When you do this, you can use `git submodule update --remote` to update the submodule with that branch:

```
# Add the submodule with the "master" branch referenced
git submodule add -b master https://github.com/holms/chef-starter.git chef-starter

# When you want to update the submodule:
git submodule update --remote

# You'll still need to commit the submodule if you want future checkouts to use the new revision
git add chef-starter
git commit -m "Update chef-starter submodule"
```

You'll still get a detached head in the submodule when you start checking out different versions of the super project (`vagarant-starter`), but at least now it's easier to update the submodule to the latest version from the remote.

You may find it easier to use git-subtree instead of submodules:

```
# First, get rid of the submodule
git submodule deinit chef-starter # If you have Git 1.8.3 or later, otherwise edit .gitmodules
git rm chef-starter               # Remove the directory
git commit -m "Removed chef-starter submodule in preparation to add as a subtree"

# Now add the subtree
git subtree add -P chef-starter https://github.com/holms/chef-starter master --squash
```

This grafts the `chef-starter` repo into the `chef-starter/` directory in your `vagrant-starter` repo. From that point forward, you don't have to do anything special if you choose to edit files in the subtree. For instance, you don't have to run `git submodule update` after cloning.

Comment: Ok, it does fits my first use-case. I don't have to store `chef-starter` dir in repo anymore, it's cool. Although, I'd like to have a `myrepo` subdir inside the `vagrant-starter` repo, which does have own git repository, and it would be completely invisible to `vagrant-starter`. Is this possible?

Comment: I've ended up using just by ignoring `chef-starter` directory, and using simple `git clone` in my makefile..

Answer (score 6):

To ensure my submodules stay synced and undetached, I have the following in a batch file.  It relies on adopting the policy of syncing to the submodule's master branch - for me this isn't a problem, I just fork the submodule and ensure it has a master.  I find it's much easier to keep track of things with this approach.

```
git pull
git submodule sync    # Ensure the submodule points to the right place
git submodule update  # Update the submodule  
git submodule foreach git checkout master  # Ensure subs are on master branch
git submodule foreach git pull origin master # Pull the latest master
```

Comment: As an update, I just wanted to mention that I prefer subtree merging as a strategy over submodules these days:
https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/

Comment: `error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git
fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for submodules/blackbox`. It happened at `git submodule foreach git checkout main`

Answer (score 2):

Use following:

1) When adding submodule use -b key to set its branch:

```
git submodule add -b master git@github.com:Bla-bla/submodule.git sm_dir
```

2) When updating submodules use --merge param to merge updates to CURRENT submodule's branch (most probably it would be `master`):

```
git submodule update --merge
```

that's all